# How to get Hadees E-books in Urdu ..?

Tags: hadith, sunni, books, language

I want to get Hadees Book in Urdu.Any Body Have then Please Share with me,if Possible.

Answer (score 1):

My urdu is not the best so I would advise you to verify the text in the below links with a urdu speaking person too:

1) **Sahih Bukhari**: https://www.urdupoint.com/islam/hadees-books/sahih-bukhari.html

2) **Sahih Muslim**: https://www.urdupoint.com/islam/hadees-books/sahih-muslim.html

3) **Sunan Abi Dawud** : https://www.urdupoint.com/islam/hadees-books/sunan-abi-dawud.html

4) **Sunan Ibn Majah** : https://www.urdupoint.com/islam/hadees-books/sunan-ibn-majah.html

5) **Sunan Nisai** : https://www.urdupoint.com/islam/hadees-books/sunan-nisai.html

6) **Sunan at Tirmidhi**: https://www.urdupoint.com/islam/hadees-books/sunan-at-tirmidhi.html

I normally verify the Hadiths on non-arabic sites with the Arabic text in the below site:

https://www.sunnah.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of scanned Hadith Books in Urdu on [archive.org](http://archive.org) so consider searching there, e.g. like [this](https://archive.org/search.php?query=sahih%20bukhari%20urdu&and[]=mediatype%3A%22texts%22), also see [kitabosunnat.com](http://kitabosunnat.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can free Download Hadith and all type of Books in Urdu:

- [here](https://pdfbooksfree.pk/hadith-books/)
- [Here](http://www.thechosenone.info/sahih-bukhari-hadith-urdu-volumes-1-8/)

Comment: Please check it back, brother. جزاک الللہ